# How to change the row values and column values in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am very new to Excel VBA

I want to change row and column values 
My data is similar to this
[image]

```
My age is   My height is    My weight is 
between 10-20   150 45
between 21-30   170 56
between 10-20   155 60
between 10-20   160 53
between 21-30   173 68
```

I want to make the data like this

[image]

```
Age Hght    Wght
Category A  150 45
Category B  170 56
Category A  155 60
Category A  160 53
Category B  173 68
```

ie I changed the first row

Then I changed all "between 10-20" to "Category A" and "between 21-30" to "Category B"

I prefer not to use column numbers in code, instead I prefer to use column names.

ie like this,
If Age="between 10-20" then Age="Category A"

How can we do it?

Comment: you would do it exactly as you described. loop through your rows and substitute cell.value  if your condition holds. try coming up with some code first, then you'll get help

Comment: for each cel in Range=("A1:A3") ; if cel.value="My age is" then cell.value="age"; next cel....... Is this correct?

Comment: if you want to see , if it works and how it works, open the vba editor and type the code in

Comment: It is also possible to create a second table with these lookups and use the normal `VLOOKUP` process to get them into the main data.  That has the advantage of updating on demand and keeps everything in Excel (and out of VBA).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you put the data in the table. (not simply type in the data in the excel's cells) 
 You should go to INSERT ribbon there insert the table.
[image: Table Name : Age Table] 

Next, follow the advice from @Bryon, create another table called "DataTable" like following figure. You may create this table at another worksheet (e.g. MyData)
 [image: Table Name : Data Table]

Lastly, you create another table called "MyResult". At the 1st row of the table, put the formula in the cell as following based on the columns : 
    =VLOOKUP(AgeTable[@[My age is]],DataTable,2,TRUE)

column 2 

    =VLOOKUP(AgeTable[@[My Height is]],AgeTable[@[My Height is]],1,TRUE)

column 3 

    =VLOOKUP(AgeTable[@[My Weight is]],AgeTable[@[My Weight is]],1,TRUE)

 Following is the output of the table:
[image: Table Name : MyResult]

Whenever values had been change at column 2 and column 3 of table 1, it will change the column 2 and column 3 of table 3